# Can I access the last computed result before a function 'stop's?

Tags: r, exception

Consider this code:

```r
bad_function <- function() {
    # a lot of code
    x <- 1
    stop("error")
}

tryCatch(bad_function(), error = function(cond) {x})
```

Obviously, `x` is not accessible in the `error` handler. But is there another way to access the value of `x` without changing `bad_function`? Alternatively, is there a way to patch `bad_function` to skip over `stop("error")` and return `x` without having to copy all that `# a lot of code`?

Comment: Are you fine with setting a breakpoint at the stop line?

Comment: @danlooo no, this is non-interactive code.

Comment: You can skip the error without changing the function using `bad_function <- purrr::possibly(bad_function, NULL)`. Then it returns a NULL in case of an error instead of stopping the whole script

Comment: @danlooo the idea is to return the last computed value in case of an error, not `NULL`. Your function returns `NULL`.

Comment: `possibly` is an adverb to wrap any function arround a `tryCatch` statement. In order to know the last computed value, the program needs to know when it will crash. Is there any R debugger allowing to step *backwards* to reassemble the env just *before* the crash?

Comment: @danloo are you asking me? I don't know, that's why I was asking the question above ;)

Comment: Step-back is really powerful but usually something you need to pay for quite much and which is not available for all languages...

Answer (score 2):

This works if the result you are looking for is named (and the you know the name - here, `x`):

```r
bad_function <- function() {
    # a lot of code
    x <- 1
    stop("error")
}

.old_stop <- base::stopifnot
.new_stop <- function(...) {
    parent.frame()$x
}

assignInNamespace("stop", .new_stop, "base")
bad_function()
assignInNamespace("stop", .old_stop, "base")
```

I still wonder if there are better solutions.

Comment: This is not a solution to an actual error handling issue.

Comment: @Roland correct. However, avoiding the x-and-y-problem, it may be a valid solution for some. And as I wrote, "I still wonder if there are _better_ solutions".

Comment: Yes, I believe your issue is not sufficiently defined. Should we assume that you only care about errors from a call to `stop`? That looks like a very artificial problem and should probably be handled within `bad_function` by replacing `stop` with a warning and a call to `return`.

Comment: @Roland what does "artificial" problem mean? I guess you mean "specific". But if you pay close attention to my question - it is quite specific, too. Also, I would love to handle that within `bad_function`, but this is a function deep inside some package that is not mine to change, and it ends with some `stopifnot(!any(is.na(...)))` that I do not need. Maybe mentioning `tryCatch` in the question title was too generic - I might change that.

Comment: I mean artificially constructed and not a real world problem. "and it ends with some stopifnot(!any(is.na(...))) that I do not need", just use `trace` to insert a `return()` statement before this code line.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the value simultaneously to `x` in the function environment, as well to another `x` in an external say debug environment that you defined beforehand.

```
ev1 <- new.env()

bad_function <- function() {
  env <- new.env(parent=baseenv())
  # a lot of code
  x <- ev1$x <- 1
  stop("error")
}

tryCatch(bad_function(), error = function(e) ev1$x)
# [1] 1
```

The advantage is that `.GlobalEnv` stays clear (apart from the environment of course).

```
ls()
# [1] "bad_function" "ev1"
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I implement this when `bad_function` is defined by someone else?